# Ghostview ...and incremental rendering

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I recall old instantiations of Ghostview that rendered complex PostScript pages incrementally.

I'm currently running GhostView 5.0 with GhostScript 9.52 on a Windows 7 computer, and now I only seem to see the finished page.

Can I reconfigure GV to run the way I remember?
Or at least specify this behavior on a command line at execution time?
Or was this feature removed at some point and for some reason?